# PHP UTF-8 bondary regex does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, php, regex

I have a CentOS 6 with newest updates running a LAMP stack.

A user is complaining that his code does not work and he is trying to use preg_match with unicode characters.

This is the code not working:

```
$regex = '/\bøl\b/iu';

preg_match($regex, "han drikker øl for sjov", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Strange thing is that this exact codes works entirely fine on other servers and I cannot work this out. I have tried several things so:

- PCRE is installed and does have UTF-8 support
- Ensured that the file is in fact UTF-8
- Tried setting mb_regex_encoding
- I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432868/php-regex-word-boundary-matching-in-utf-8) question too but, it works on other servers without this and just as it is in my example
- mbstring() is installed
- PHP version is 5.3 and is the vendor supplied package from yum

Also I have just tested it on an installation built by hand from source, and on there it works like a charm - but I'd rather not build the packages by hand.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting this result? Array ( [0] => Ã¸l ) or not any result...

Comment: You need to specify your PHP version and where you obtained it.

Comment: @ChintanGor, no result at all, apache is serving UTF-8 and it works if I remove boundaies.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have added that explicitly, although I thought "I have a CentOS 6 with newest updates running a LAMP stack" covered it :)

Comment: Can you try to use var_dump instead print_r, please? To see returned data type